# Office PowerPoint: how to apply a new Design I created via ActivePresentation.Designs.Add()

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a new slide master and apply it to current presentation, code below:

```
    var design = app.ActivePresentation.Designs.Add("my own design");
    app.ActivePresentation.Apply??
```

I tried ApplyTheme and ApplyTemplate, they all throw exception

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80048240): Presentation (unknown member) : Invalid request.  PowerPoint could not open the file.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PresentationClass.ApplyTheme(String themeName)
```

Any idea? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range.Design = design
```